# Docusign - No HTTP response when document is declined

Tags: docusignapi

I've been tasked with continuing to support/update a Docusign API setup made by my predecessor, and I've been having some trouble with the HTTP responses from Docusign related to documents being declined.

As far as I understand, I am sent signed copies of the Docusign document whenever one or more of my signers complete their portion. However, I have yet to receive one whenever I decline an envelope.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: StackOverflow is not really an appropriate forum for this question, since it's not technical in nature. I'd suggest you instead post to the DocuSign Community forum: http://community.docusign.com/.

Comment: @KimBrandl I've been redirected from when I posted on the DocuSign forums to post on here. Guess I'll wait to see which side budges first.

Comment: If you are saying that you are receiving the documents as the recipients complete and sign them, what exactly do you want to have happen when someone declines to sign?  If they decline to sign then that means they have not made any alterations to the document or envelope at all, so whomever was last to sign - that should be the latest version of the document.

Comment: @Ergin I am using both Alphatrust and Docusign as my e-signature implementations, and Alphatrust sends responses whenever their document status changes. I was wondering whether Docusign had any similar implementation, or whether I would have to poll continuously for my envelope's status to find out whether it was declined or not.

Comment: Ok that's a different question, in that case I believe Kim has answered your question. In summary, there are 3 ways for you to get envelope status. You can poll the DocuSign service every so often, continuously checking for change in status, OR you can have the DocuSign platform push real-time updates out to an external listener you've setup using DocuSign Connect, which works at the account level, OR you can use the `envelopeNotifications` feature, which is at the envelope level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My apologies for the comment above -- I misunderstood your original question.)

If you're looking for DocuSign to automatically send you (i.e., your application) a notification via HTTP POST whenever an Envelope is Declined, then you can accomplish this in either one of two ways:

- By configuring **DocuSign Connect** (at the account level).  See the Dev Center (https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect) and the Connect Service Guide (http://764be237d39fdfa0985f-37a6c1f0731907180d9764651d02bea9.r5.cf2.rackcdn.com/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf) for more info.

OR

- By specifying **eventNotification** (at the Envelope level) as part of the **Create Envelope** API request for each Envelope.  For info on this, search the REST API Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) for **eventNotification**.